# Confused with the flow of async / await functions

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following classes:

DataAccessFactory:

```
public class DataAccessFactory
{
    public static IUserAccessLayer User() => new UserAccessLayer(new DataContext());
    public static IAuthenticationAccessLayer Authentication() => new AuthenticationAccessLayer(new DataAccess.DataContext());
}
```

AuthenticationAccessLayer:

```
public class AuthenticationAccessLayer : IAuthenticationAccessLayer
{
    private readonly DataContext context;

    public AuthenticationAccessLayer(DataContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async void RegisterAsync(UserRegisterModel model)
    {
        context.User.Add(new UserModel()
        {
            EmailAddress = model.Email,
            PasswordHash = model.PasswordHash,
            PasswordSalt = model.PasswordSalt
        });
    }

    public async Task<bool> EmailExist(string email)
    {
        var user = await context.User.Where(x => x.EmailAddress.Equals(email)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (user == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

UserStore:

```
public class UserStore : ViewModelBase
{
    public UserStore()
    {
    }

    public UserStore(int userID)
    {
        this.UserID = userID;
    }

    #region Authentication

    public async Task<bool> AuthenticateAsync(LoginModel model)
    {
        return await DataAccessFactory.Authentication().LoginAsync(model);
    }

    public async void RegisterUserAsync(UserRegisterModel model)
    {
        var store = DataAccessFactory.Authentication();

        //check if unique email
        if(await store.EmailExist(model.Email))
            throw new ValidationException($"Email {model.Email} is already registered.");

        store.RegisterAsync(model);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

My question is, in the UserStore, in the `RegisterUserAsync` function, will the `UserRegisterModel` get added to the DB before the `EmailExist` function returns or throw an exception?

Comment: The `AuthenticationAccessLayer.RegisterAsync` is not actually `async`. The `context.User.Add` is not returned, nor is it `Task` returning...

Comment: You should also [Avoid async void methods](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your RegisterUserAsync method will be executed after the EmailExist method returns.

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx)

> The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to
>   suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes.
>   The task represents ongoing work.
>   ...
>   An await expression does not block the thread on which it is
>   executing. Instead, it causes the compiler to sign up the rest of the
>   async method as a continuation on the awaited task. Control then
>   returns to the caller of the async method. When the task completes, it
>   invokes its continuation, and execution of the async method resumes
>   where it left off.

Comment: Okay I think I get it. The method execution after the await is suspended, but the thread is free to execute other, for instance, UI specific stuff. It will not execute after the await until the EmailExist returns a value?

Answer (score 0):

It will throw the `ValidateException` if the email exists, because you are awaiting the `EmailExist` function.

Answer (score -1):

It will depend on the thread scheduler probably. However, if you define `RegisterUserAsync` to be something like

```
    public async Task RegisterUserAsync(UserRegisterModel model)
    {
        var store = DataAccessFactory.Authentication();

        //check if unique email
        if(await store.EmailExist(model.Email))
            throw new ValidationException($"Email {model.Email} is already registered.");

        await store.RegisterAsync(model);
    }
```

Then `RegisterAsync` will execute after `EmailExist`. (notice the Task return type and the await keyword.)

Comment: Even if the method *is* `async void` `RegisterAsync` still can't run before `EmailExist` finishes.  `RegisterUserAsync` will simply return before it's done, and not give it's caller (who is not shown) a way of knowing when it's finished.